# Symfony 5 Heroku Unable to create a signed JWT from the given configuration

Tags: symfony, heroku, jwt, symfony5

So, I have deployed a JWT project in Heroku and I get following error

```
 Uncaught PHP Exception Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Exception\JWTEncodeFailureException: "Unable to create a signed JWT from the given configuration." at /app/vendor/lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle/Encoder/LcobucciJWTEncoder.php line 38
```

.env

```
APP_ENV=prod
APP_SECRET=4b3623b38e2d6ba78fe9vdfx59dc3dd5
JWT_SECRET_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem
JWT_PASSPHRASE=pass
DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/task.db"
```

In git cmd I also did, but didn't worked.

```
heroku config:set APP_ENV=prod
heroku config:set JWT_SECRET_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem
etc
```

In localhost it is working well JWT Token is generating fine but in heroku I get above error.

Comment: Have you checked that the certificates are actually deployed (or generated)? By default they are added to `.gitignore`, so depending on your deployment method they might not be.

Comment: Did you find any solution for your problem? 
I can see that pem-files are generated correct on server. I can generate tokens using `bin/console lexik:jwt:generate-token` command but when calling /login I always get the "Unable to create a signed JWT from the given configuration." error :( 
Locally, everything is fine. I have no more ideas..

Answer (score 10):

if you used lexit have you thought of regenerating your private and public keys on your production environnement?

```
php bin/console lexik:jwt:generate-keypair
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently and as @php-abs metioned, I just added it to the composer.json file in the scripts/auto-scripts section as a command as shown bellow:

```
"scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
            "lexik:jwt:generate-keypair": "symfony-cmd"
        },
...
}
```